# Make grid fit the content

Tags: html, css

I have some code that I need to modify to make it so that the grid rows will generate in a dynamic way as the content expands. Is there any way to do this without manually adding extra divs for it to function properly? I'm trying to make sure that the code is as efficient as possible, and I'm wondering if there is a better solution that doesn't involve having to add empty divs manually. I'm looking for the best way to make sure that the code is running optimally and that the grid rows are generating in the most efficient manner possible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    .wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
      border: 1px solid black;
      grid-gap: 1px;
      background-color: black;
      position: relative;
    }

    .wrapper > .item {
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
      background-color: #41BA23;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .text-1 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      text-align: left;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      }
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item">
              <div class="text-1">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at odio at sapien volutpat commodo quis sed ligula. Vestibulum sed rutrum risus. Nullam imperdiet leo ac ex sodales condimentum. Nunc ut neque sit amet sapien vestibulum efficitur vel vitae magna. Etiam pretium mauris nisi, sit amet vulputate mi iaculis vel. Aliquam euismod commodo mattis. Integer molestie, tortor at venenatis aliquam, velit arcu commodo sapien, eget suscipit diam arcu non eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum eget lacus a felis mollis convallis at id mi. Pellentesque nulla turpis, tempus a erat vitae, congue egestas ligula. Pellentesque venenatis quam nulla, id maximus ante pharetra a. Aenean sagittis nulla urna, sed congue purus semper non. Ut accumsan tortor at condimentum rhoncus. Suspendisse hendrerit sit amet lectus at mollis. Aliquam nec lorem dapibus, condimentum mauris id, mollis nisi.

Phasellus quis est non magna fringilla suscipit. Nulla commodo velit non diam tempus iaculis. Pellentesque feugiat, augue a fringilla placerat, ex quam dapibus eros, eu convallis dolor magna quis diam. Vestibulum et tempus felis. Sed posuere odio nunc, non convallis tellus sagittis vel. Integer luctus, eros ultrices accumsan aliquet, dui nulla pretium nisi, a placerat eros lectus non turpis. Phasellus interdum elementum felis eu faucibus. Quisque semper facilisis risus, in pulvinar ligula aliquam non. Donec gravida erat pharetra enim finibus tincidunt.

Sed quis turpis blandit, rutrum dui et, feugiat turpis. Curabitur non semper lectus. Nunc diam magna, pulvinar placerat sollicitudin mattis, lacinia ac augue. Ut feugiat faucibus urna, et bibendum risus iaculis ut. Aliquam condimentum metus quis ipsum fringilla, id interdum libero molestie. Nulla vel fermentum justo. Fusce justo quam, consectetur nec pharetra eget, iaculis quis diam. Sed convallis fringilla neque, tristique mollis ex venenatis non. Duis varius odio non sem volutpat, ac commodo lectus varius. Phasellus non mi nec est lacinia mattis in sit amet est. Proin nibh magna, congue ac dui ut, commodo maximus dui. Vestibulum at diam ut lorem semper interdum sit amet eget erat. Maecenas pharetra risus a sapien venenatis fermentum. Cras placerat dignissim mauris in sodales. Cras quis urna pharetra neque pharetra consequat. Proin quis felis libero.

Curabitur vitae dapibus nunc. Phasellus ante purus, bibendum et magna ut, malesuada dictum nisl. Suspendisse ac eros eu lectus imperdiet consequat ut sed est. Duis sit amet pretium dui. Proin auctor nisi eu tempor vestibulum. Aenean eleifend diam quis elit tristique interdum. Nulla facilisi.

Vestibulum vehicula lacinia libero quis euismod. Morbi volutpat congue enim, at auctor lectus vulputate ut. Donec enim eros, egestas eget felis vel, aliquet auctor elit. Duis sodales sagittis eros, vel cursus nisi ullamcorper vel. Vestibulum euismod sit amet lorem ac molestie. Pellentesque euismod ultrices elit sit amet suscipit. Vestibulum porttitor varius urna, ut scelerisque sapien vestibulum laoreet. Donec sit amet magna tincidunt, euismod neque non, eleifend metus. Nunc pulvinar est sit amet ullamcorper aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam eu velit metus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at odio at sapien volutpat commodo quis sed ligula. Vestibulum sed rutrum risus. Nullam imperdiet leo ac ex sodales condimentum. Nunc ut neque sit amet sapien vestibulum efficitur vel vitae magna. Etiam pretium mauris nisi, sit amet vulputate mi iaculis vel. Aliquam euismod commodo mattis. Integer molestie, tortor at venenatis aliquam, velit arcu commodo sapien, eget suscipit diam arcu non eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum eget lacus a felis mollis convallis at id mi. Pellentesque nulla turpis, tempus a erat vitae, congue egestas ligula. Pellentesque venenatis quam nulla, id maximus ante pharetra a. Aenean sagittis nulla urna, sed congue purus semper non. Ut accumsan tortor at condimentum rhoncus. Suspendisse hendrerit sit amet lectus at mollis. Aliquam nec lorem dapibus, condimentum mauris id, mollis nisi.

Phasellus quis est non magna fringilla suscipit. Nulla commodo velit non diam tempus iaculis. Pellentesque feugiat, augue a fringilla placerat, ex quam dapibus eros, eu convallis dolor magna quis diam. Vestibulum et tempus felis. Sed posuere odio nunc, non convallis tellus sagittis vel. Integer luctus, eros ultrices accumsan aliquet, dui nulla pretium nisi, a placerat eros lectus non turpis. Phasellus interdum elementum felis eu faucibus. Quisque semper facilisis risus, in pulvinar ligula aliquam non. Donec gravida erat pharetra enim finibus tincidunt.

Sed quis turpis blandit, rutrum dui et, feugiat turpis. Curabitur non semper lectus. Nunc diam magna, pulvinar placerat sollicitudin mattis, lacinia ac augue. Ut feugiat faucibus urna, et bibendum risus iaculis ut. Aliquam condimentum metus quis ipsum fringilla, id interdum libero molestie. Nulla vel fermentum justo. Fusce justo quam, consectetur nec pharetra eget, iaculis quis diam. Sed convallis fringilla neque, tristique mollis ex venenatis non. Duis varius odio non sem volutpat, ac commodo lectus varius. Phasellus non mi nec est lacinia mattis in sit amet est. Proin nibh magna, congue ac dui ut, commodo maximus dui. Vestibulum at diam ut lorem semper interdum sit amet eget erat. Maecenas pharetra risus a sapien venenatis fermentum. Cras placerat dignissim mauris in sodales. Cras quis urna pharetra neque pharetra consequat. Proin quis felis libero.

Curabitur vitae dapibus nunc. Phasellus ante purus, bibendum et magna ut, malesuada dictum nisl. Suspendisse ac eros eu lectus imperdiet consequat ut sed est. Duis sit amet pretium dui. Proin auctor nisi eu tempor vestibulum. Aenean eleifend diam quis elit tristique interdum. Nulla facilisi.

Vestibulum vehicula lacinia libero quis euismod. Morbi volutpat congue enim, at auctor lectus vulputate ut. Donec enim eros, egestas eget felis vel, aliquet auctor elit. Duis sodales sagittis eros, vel cursus nisi ullamcorper vel. Vestibulum euismod sit amet lorem ac molestie. Pellentesque euismod ultrices elit sit amet suscipit. Vestibulum porttitor varius urna, ut scelerisque sapien vestibulum laoreet. Donec sit amet magna tincidunt, euismod neque non, eleifend metus. Nunc pulvinar est sit amet ullamcorper aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam eu velit metus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at odio at sapien volutpat commodo quis sed ligula. Vestibulum sed rutrum risus. Nullam imperdiet leo ac ex sodales condimentum. Nunc ut neque sit amet sapien vestibulum efficitur vel vitae magna. Etiam pretium mauris nisi, sit amet vulputate mi iaculis vel. Aliquam euismod commodo mattis. Integer molestie, tortor at venenatis aliquam, velit arcu commodo sapien, eget suscipit diam arcu non eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum eget lacus a felis mollis convallis at id mi. Pellentesque nulla turpis, tempus a erat vitae, congue egestas ligula. Pellentesque venenatis quam nulla, id maximus ante pharetra a. Aenean sagittis nulla urna, sed congue purus semper non. Ut accumsan tortor at condimentum rhoncus. Suspendisse hendrerit sit amet lectus at mollis. Aliquam nec lorem dapibus, condimentum mauris id, mollis nisi.

Phasellus quis est non magna fringilla suscipit. Nulla commodo velit non diam tempus iaculis. Pellentesque feugiat, augue a fringilla placerat, ex quam dapibus eros, eu convallis dolor magna quis diam. Vestibulum et tempus felis. Sed posuere odio nunc, non convallis tellus sagittis vel. Integer luctus, eros ultrices accumsan aliquet, dui nulla pretium nisi, a placerat eros lectus non turpis. Phasellus interdum elementum felis eu faucibus. Quisque semper facilisis risus, in pulvinar ligula aliquam non. Donec gravida erat pharetra enim finibus tincidunt.

Sed quis turpis blandit, rutrum dui et, feugiat turpis. Curabitur non semper lectus. Nunc diam magna, pulvinar placerat sollicitudin mattis, lacinia ac augue. Ut feugiat faucibus urna, et bibendum risus iaculis ut. Aliquam condimentum metus quis ipsum fringilla, id interdum libero molestie. Nulla vel fermentum justo. Fusce justo quam, consectetur nec pharetra eget, iaculis quis diam. Sed convallis fringilla neque, tristique mollis ex venenatis non. Duis varius odio non sem volutpat, ac commodo lectus varius. Phasellus non mi nec est lacinia mattis in sit amet est. Proin nibh magna, congue ac dui ut, commodo maximus dui. Vestibulum at diam ut lorem semper interdum sit amet eget erat. Maecenas pharetra risus a sapien venenatis fermentum. Cras placerat dignissim mauris in sodales. Cras quis urna pharetra neque pharetra consequat. Proin quis felis libero.

Curabitur vitae dapibus nunc. Phasellus ante purus, bibendum et magna ut, malesuada dictum nisl. Suspendisse ac eros eu lectus imperdiet consequat ut sed est. Duis sit amet pretium dui. Proin auctor nisi eu tempor vestibulum. Aenean eleifend diam quis elit tristique interdum. Nulla facilisi.

Vestibulum vehicula lacinia libero quis euismod. Morbi volutpat congue enim, at auctor lectus vulputate ut. Donec enim eros, egestas eget felis vel, aliquet auctor elit. Duis sodales sagittis eros, vel cursus nisi ullamcorper vel. Vestibulum euismod sit amet lorem ac molestie. Pellentesque euismod ultrices elit sit amet suscipit. Vestibulum porttitor varius urna, ut scelerisque sapien vestibulum laoreet. Donec sit amet magna tincidunt, euismod neque non, eleifend metus. Nunc pulvinar est sit amet ullamcorper aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam eu velit metus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at odio at sapien volutpat commodo quis sed ligula. Vestibulum sed rutrum risus. Nullam imperdiet leo ac ex sodales condimentum. Nunc ut neque sit amet sapien vestibulum efficitur vel vitae magna. Etiam pretium mauris nisi, sit amet vulputate mi iaculis vel. Aliquam euismod commodo mattis. Integer molestie, tortor at venenatis aliquam, velit arcu commodo sapien, eget suscipit diam arcu non eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum eget lacus a felis mollis convallis at id mi. Pellentesque nulla turpis, tempus a erat vitae, congue egestas ligula. Pellentesque venenatis quam nulla, id maximus ante pharetra a. Aenean sagittis nulla urna, sed congue purus semper non. Ut accumsan tortor at condimentum rhoncus. Suspendisse hendrerit sit amet lectus at mollis. Aliquam nec lorem dapibus, condimentum mauris id, mollis nisi.

Phasellus quis est non magna fringilla suscipit. Nulla commodo velit non diam tempus iaculis. Pellentesque feugiat, augue a fringilla placerat, ex quam dapibus eros, eu convallis dolor magna quis diam. Vestibulum et tempus felis. Sed posuere odio nunc, non convallis tellus sagittis vel. Integer luctus, eros ultrices accumsan aliquet, dui nulla pretium nisi, a placerat eros lectus non turpis. Phasellus interdum elementum felis eu faucibus. Quisque semper facilisis risus, in pulvinar ligula aliquam non. Donec gravida erat pharetra enim finibus tincidunt.

Sed quis turpis blandit, rutrum dui et, feugiat turpis. Curabitur non semper lectus. Nunc diam magna, pulvinar placerat sollicitudin mattis, lacinia ac augue. Ut feugiat faucibus urna, et bibendum risus iaculis ut. Aliquam condimentum metus quis ipsum fringilla, id interdum libero molestie. Nulla vel fermentum justo. Fusce justo quam, consectetur nec pharetra eget, iaculis quis diam. Sed convallis fringilla neque, tristique mollis ex venenatis non. Duis varius odio non sem volutpat, ac commodo lectus varius. Phasellus non mi nec est lacinia mattis in sit amet est. Proin nibh magna, congue ac dui ut, commodo maximus dui. Vestibulum at diam ut lorem semper interdum sit amet eget erat. Maecenas pharetra risus a sapien venenatis fermentum. Cras placerat dignissim mauris in sodales. Cras quis urna pharetra neque pharetra consequat. Proin quis felis libero.

Curabitur vitae dapibus nunc. Phasellus ante purus, bibendum et magna ut, malesuada dictum nisl. Suspendisse ac eros eu lectus imperdiet consequat ut sed est. Duis sit amet pretium dui. Proin auctor nisi eu tempor vestibulum. Aenean eleifend diam quis elit tristique interdum. Nulla facilisi.

Vestibulum vehicula lacinia libero quis euismod. Morbi volutpat congue enim, at auctor lectus vulputate ut. Donec enim eros, egestas eget felis vel, aliquet auctor elit. Duis sodales sagittis eros, vel cursus nisi ullamcorper vel. Vestibulum euismod sit amet lorem ac molestie. Pellentesque euismod ultrices elit sit amet suscipit. Vestibulum porttitor varius urna, ut scelerisque sapien vestibulum laoreet. Donec sit amet magna tincidunt, euismod neque non, eleifend metus. Nunc pulvinar est sit amet ullamcorper aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam eu velit metus.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at odio at sapien volutpat commodo quis sed ligula. Vestibulum sed rutrum risus. Nullam imperdiet leo ac ex sodales condimentum. Nunc ut neque sit amet sapien vestibulum efficitur vel vitae magna. Etiam pretium mauris nisi, sit amet vulputate mi iaculis vel. Aliquam euismod commodo mattis. Integer molestie, tortor at venenatis aliquam, velit arcu commodo sapien, eget suscipit diam arcu non eros. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum eget lacus a felis mollis convallis at id mi. Pellentesque nulla turpis, tempus a erat vitae, congue egestas ligula. Pellentesque venenatis quam nulla, id maximus ante pharetra a. Aenean sagittis nulla urna, sed congue purus semper non. Ut accumsan tortor at condimentum rhoncus. Suspendisse hendrerit sit amet lectus at mollis. Aliquam nec lorem dapibus, condimentum mauris id, mollis nisi.

Phasellus quis est non magna fringilla suscipit. Nulla commodo velit non diam tempus iaculis. Pellentesque feugiat, augue a fringilla placerat, ex quam dapibus eros, eu convallis dolor magna quis diam. Vestibulum et tempus felis. Sed posuere odio nunc, non convallis tellus sagittis vel. Integer luctus, eros ultrices accumsan aliquet, dui nulla pretium nisi, a placerat eros lectus non turpis. Phasellus interdum elementum felis eu faucibus. Quisque semper facilisis risus, in pulvinar ligula aliquam non. Donec gravida erat pharetra enim finibus tincidunt.

Sed quis turpis blandit, rutrum dui et, feugiat turpis. Curabitur non semper lectus. Nunc diam magna, pulvinar placerat sollicitudin mattis, lacinia ac augue. Ut feugiat faucibus urna, et bibendum risus iaculis ut. Aliquam condimentum metus quis ipsum fringilla, id interdum libero molestie. Nulla vel fermentum justo. Fusce justo quam, consectetur nec pharetra eget, iaculis quis diam. Sed convallis fringilla neque, tristique mollis ex venenatis non. Duis varius odio non sem volutpat, ac commodo lectus varius. Phasellus non mi nec est lacinia mattis in sit amet est. Proin nibh magna, congue ac dui ut, commodo maximus dui. Vestibulum at diam ut lorem semper interdum sit amet eget erat. Maecenas pharetra risus a sapien venenatis fermentum. Cras placerat dignissim mauris in sodales. Cras quis urna pharetra neque pharetra consequat. Proin quis felis libero.

Curabitur vitae dapibus nunc. Phasellus ante purus, bibendum et magna ut, malesuada dictum nisl. Suspendisse ac eros eu lectus imperdiet consequat ut sed est. Duis sit amet pretium dui. Proin auctor nisi eu tempor vestibulum. Aenean eleifend diam quis elit tristique interdum. Nulla facilisi.

Vestibulum vehicula lacinia libero quis euismod. Morbi volutpat congue enim, at auctor lectus vulputate ut. Donec enim eros, egestas eget felis vel, aliquet auctor elit. Duis sodales sagittis eros, vel cursus nisi ullamcorper vel. Vestibulum euismod sit amet lorem ac molestie. Pellentesque euismod ultrices elit sit amet suscipit. Vestibulum porttitor varius urna, ut scelerisque sapien vestibulum laoreet. Donec sit amet magna tincidunt, euismod neque non, eleifend metus. Nunc pulvinar est sit amet ullamcorper aliquam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam eu velit metus.
              </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It depends on how you get your data. If you have to call a rest api for example, you could use javascript to call it and add the rows dynamically based on the data you receive from it.

Comment: I think it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. What exactly do you mean by "that the grid rows will generate in a dynamic way as the content expands". Do you want the cells to grow in width aka spanning multiple columns? Or do you want them to grow in height? Or both, while keeping the 1:1 aspect ratio?